# Using Bearer Authentication with Azure Active Directory Access Tokens

Tags: token, azure-active-directory, passport.js, bearer-token

I am using the [Passport AAD project](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) with the bearer strategy to protect my endpoints. After I receive tokens with the OIDC strategy when logging in, I can't seem to get the bearer strategy to validate the signature of the access token. I get:

```
authentication failed due to: invalid signature
```

I have no problems validating the id_token, but I would prefer not to use this for our client app if the id_token can't be refreshed with AAD. Also, when using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to test the validation with the [published public keys](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys), I see the same issue (can validate the id_token, but not the access_token).

Am I missing a step when grabbing the access token, or is there a gap in my understanding of how access tokens are validated?

**Update with more details**

I am requesting an access token from my tenant:

```
identityMetadata: https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration,
responseType: 'id_token code'
```

Using the OIDCStrategy in the AAD Passport project.

```
const callbackOIDC = (iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) => {
  return done(null,{
    profile,
    accessToken,
    refreshToken
  });
};

passport.use(new OIDCStrategy(config.creds, callbackOIDC));
```

Then I run authenticate, shown below:

```
auth.adCallback = function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', {
    response: res,
    resourceURL: 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
    session: false
  }, function (err, user, info) {
    console.log(user.access_token);
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

I think I may have been asking for a graph access token above by specifying the resource URL. If I remove that resource URL, I still get an access token, but the bearer strategy throws an invalid token error (instead of an invalid signature error). Is there a different resource URL I should be setting to match with my tenant and get the access token I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

What access tokens are you requesting? If the access token is meant to be used against the Microsoft Graph, for example, it is the Graph's task to validate them- not your app's.
Can you expand on the exact scenario you are trying to implement, and at what point you need to refresh id_tokens?

Comment: You were right about the graph access token. Still a bit confused as to how I can get an access token for my AAD tenant and added a bit more info in my original question.